# ffmpeg video of image list within a folder

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, terminal

I am trying to create an animation from a png files. They are all in the same folder and are named

```
step0.png
step1.png
step2.png
.....

step19998.png
step19999.png
```

I frame represents 0.01s, so I think I need 100 fps.

the command I was trying:

```
ffmpeg -r 100 -f image2 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' -vcodec libx264 -crf 1  -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```

For some reason it doesnt put them together in the correct order, but when i put the last 500 into another folder and ran the command there it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing leading zeros for most of your steps, which is why they won't sort correctly. For example:

```
for i in $(seq 1 20); do
 echo "step$i.png"
done | sort
```

yields

```
step10.png
step11.png
step12.png
step13.png
step14.png
step15.png
step16.png
step17.png
step18.png
step19.png
step1.png
step20.png
step2.png
step3.png
step4.png
step5.png
step6.png
step7.png
step8.png
step9.png
```

Observe the wrong order. Conversely, leading zeros fix the issue. Prepending zeros like this

```
for i in $(seq 1 20); do
printf "step%02d.png\n" $i
done | sort
```

yields the sequence

```
step01.png
step02.png
step03.png
step04.png
step05.png
step06.png
step07.png
step08.png
step09.png
step10.png
step11.png
step12.png
step13.png
step14.png
step15.png
step16.png
step17.png
step18.png
step19.png
step20.png
```

As you probably want. So, I recommend adding leading zeros the filenames.

A simple hack to rename the file would be:

```
for num in $(seq 0 19999); do
  fnum=$(printf "%05d" $num)
  mv "step${num}.png" "step${fnum}.png"
done
```

Comment: Thank you, is there an easy way to rename the files?

Comment: Thank you very much!